# Can I wire a light with 3 switches in a 4-way switch configuration with one switch being a dimmer?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have an overhead light wired with a single-pole dimmer switch on one side of the room and a 3-way non-dimmer switch on the other.  I would like to add a third switch to this circuit if it's possible without losing the ability to dim the light.  Is this possible?  Also, the wiring diagrams I've found online all have the power going into the first (3-way) switch.  In my situation the power enters at the ceiling fixture.  What do I need to do differently for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a page I just found with [diagrams for various 4-way configurations](http://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/4_way_switch_diagram.html), including one with one of the 3-way switches being a dimmer.

Here is a [3-way dimmer switch from Lutron](http://www.destinationlighting.com/storeitem.jhtml?iid=3776).

Looks like I'm all set!

Comment: Another option with that many switches is to consider using "smart switches" (http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-different-types-of-smart-switches-that-are-on-the). Especially if you can't change wiring (eg, when retrofitting), it's a good option. If you have a few lights, they can also make it easier to use by setting up scenes.