# What is the most common home automation technology?

Tags: home-automation

I will soon move in my new house and I am looking to create a custom home automation system using what already exists on the market.

The most important thing would be to interface well with existing products on the market, for example lamps, fridge, television, etc. Is there one mainstream radio technology that can communicate safely with most devices?

I don't want to build my own lamps, but I wouldn't mind putting together an "automation box" to meet my needs, do you have any advice?

Comment: For newer tech, I've been keeping an eye on this startup: http://smartthings.com/ (wifi based automation devices) as well as this product from Phillips (mainly for automating lighting): http://www.meethue.com/en-US

Comment: Is your question a dup of [this one](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-different-types-of-smart-switches-that-are-on-the)?

Comment: BMitch: No, it's not. I want to build my own switch, so I need to know what technology to use, should I use a mix of them? I will decide what device to buy, what brand based on the radio technology they use and how well they can interact.

Comment: This question might be a bit localized, since technology changes at a rapid pace.  What's common today, may be gone tomorrow.

Comment: Still, vendors will choose the best technology on the market and will try to stick to it as long as it's working well. Especially if they want their product to interact with each others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the most common technologies/protocols based on my experience purchasing devices:

- [Zwave](http://www.z-wave.com/modules/ZwaveStart/): proprietary, wireless, and [tons of devices available](http://www.smarthome.com/_/Z_Wave_Compatible/_/23V/land.aspx)
- [Insteon](http://www.insteon.net/): Uses power lines and a wireless radio for redundancy (dual-band)
- [ZigBee](http://www.zigbee.org/): Wireless, but shares the same spectrum as cordless phones, microwaves, etc. But you can purchase ZigBee chips without having a OEM license, so that can mean cheaper in some instances

Also, keep an eye on [enOcean](http://www.enocean.com/en/home/) devices that will be getting cheaper and cheaper. They are used mostly in larger corporate buildings right now, but that could change as controller prices come down.

As far as getting started, you need some sort of controller to interface with all your devices. Have a look at [MiCasVerde](http://micasaverde.com/vera-lite.php) controller which connects to zwave devices (and many Insteon devices if you buy an additional plug component). That gives you tons of devices to interface with, but mostly on the lighting, temperature, door-locks, etc. Setting it up for controlling TV and fridge would not be trivial.

Hope that helps!